# Implement spell check and maintain dictionary for individual Users?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, spell-checking

I need to implement the spell check functionality for textboxes in my web application . Currently i have seen a few examples of the spell check functionality one of which is the RadSpell check ,jQuery spell check etc they all tend to save the corrected words on a spell check to a common place example the radspell check tends to save the corrected spellings to the txt file en-US-Custom.txt  under the APP_Data folder of the web project .

Since my application lets multiple users to log in and hence each user will have his set of words and would not want them to be replaced by the words of another user .!!!!

Is it possible to implement the spell check where in i can maintain words for a particular user and not let the words be overwritten by another user ?????

Thanks & Regards,
Francis

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into:
http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Spell_Checker/

I used DevExpress windows form spellchecker and where able to have customized user dictionary. You can see if its possible in the ASP-spellchecker component too.